# Form post posting null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post some information from a form but it keeps posting null values to the Comment controller rather than what is entered on the page....

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitComment", "Comment",FormMethod.Post))
{
     <fieldset>
        <legend>Submit a comment</legend>
        <input id="comment" type="text" />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the code of your `SubmitComment` action on your `CommentController`?

Comment: Please post code for SubmitComment action. How you are handling this.

Answer (score 4):

Add the `name="comment"` attribute to the input.